# Compilation Error "fatal error: openssl rc4.h: No such file or directory"

Tags: compiler

I am trying to compile the following exploit http://pastebin.com/pxy4GiFQ to use it against one of my lab machines.

I am trying to compile it inside KALI machine and get the following error:

```
root@kali:~/Desktop# gcc -o OpenFuck abc.c -lcrypto
abc.c:22:26: fatal error: openssl rc4.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

I searched online for possible solutions and ran both:

```
root@kali:~/Desktop# apt-get install libboost-dev
root@kali:~/Desktop# apt-get install libssl-dev
```

However, the error still there !

Comment: You asked another question about a problem when compiling (the same problem) and it was closed as being off-topic.  Compilation problems may fit on unix.stackexchange.com but check with them first in chat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this will not answer your question, at least I will give you a security advice.

First is first, when working as a developer, building code or compiling code you SHOULD not use the root account. It looks to me like if you were using your root account by default to do such unrelated to administation tasks. Also you will face some problems like having your binaries build with permissions that will allow only the root to execute/access them.

Also, as a quick answer to your question:

1. Be sure you have include the rc4.h with &lt rc4.h &gt and not with "rc4.h".

If this is fine:

1. Try to find you rc4.h file (locate rc4.h or find -name rc4.h /usr/include)
2. Once you have find it, add to your compilation line "-I/path/to/dir"

Hope this helps you.